# How to understand the &-sign in Less/SCSS?

Tags: css, less, scss-mixins

I'm trying to understand the & sign in Less. According to lesscss.org, the & represents the current selector parent. So what does it mean in the instance below? The css for the container class is obvious. But what does the &-footer, .CancelButton and &-thresholds apply to?

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  margin: 8px 0 8px 0;
  line-height: 32px;

  &-footer {
    display: flex;
    margin: 24px 0 8px 8px;
    height: 32px;
    justify-content: flex-end;

    .CancelButton {
      margin: 0;
    }
  }

  &-thresholds {
    margin: 24px 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: The way you have set it out; you'll be targeting two classes called `.container-footer` and `.container-thresholds`

Comment: And the CancelButton applies if an element also has the container-footer class?

Comment: It becomes `.container-footer .CancelButton`, so not if it *also* has that class; for that you'd need `&.CancelButton`.

Comment: see also [this blog post](https://css-tricks.com/the-sass-ampersand/) maybe this helps clear things up a bit.

Comment: Alright. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should think about the & sign simply replacing it with the current parent selector.

This means:

```
.container {

    &-white {
        background: white;
    }
}
```

becomes

```
.container-white {
    background: white;
}
```

or:

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    &:after {
         content: ' ';
         background: black;
    }
}
```

becomes:

```
 .container {
      display: flex;
 }
 .container:after {
      contente: ' ';
      background: black;
 }
```

EDIT:
Regarding your example:

```
.container {
    display: flex;

    &-footer {
        display: flex;
        margin: 24px 0 8px 8px;

        .CancelButton {
            margin: 0;
        }
    }
 }
```

The margin on the CancelButton class will be applied only if there will be something like:

```
<div class="container-footer">
    <button class="CancelButton" />
</div>
```

(please consider not to use CamelCase for css! Also take a look at the [BEM](http://getbem.com/introduction/) naming convention)